# Cannot render raw html in a Razor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a following Razor component (Blazor serverside?) in ASP.Core 3.0 razor pages (normal) project:

```
@using WEKA.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html

<div class="jobs-list">
    @foreach (var e in News)
    {
        <div class="job" data-aos="fade-up">
            <a href="@e.Link">
                <div class="col name">@e.Text)</div>
                <div class="col more">Detail</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    public List<QNewsList> News
    {
        set { }
        get
        {
            using (WEKAContext db = new WEKAContext())
            {
                var q = from n in db.Qaktuality select new QNewsList() { Datum = n.Datum.ToString("d.M.YYYY"), Text = new HtmlString(n.Text), Link = n.RssLink };
                return q.ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class QNewsList
    {
        public string Datum;
        public HtmlString Text;
        public string Link;
    }
}
```

The component is rendered in a normal cshtml razor page:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<WEKA.Components.NewsList>(RenderMode.Static))
```

I am trying to make the database field `Text` appear on the web page as raw HTML (i.e. rendering `&nbsp;` as a space). The `Html` object is not available here to call `Html.Raw`. 
This code above does not render raw html from database. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0#invoke-javascript-functions-from-net-methods) and from what @Hrnk has said, you need to use `MarkupString` instead of `HtmlString` in razor component.Change code to below

```
@using WEKA.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html

<div class="jobs-list">
    @foreach (var e in News)
    {
        <div class="job" data-aos="fade-up">
            <a href="@e.Link">
                <div class="col name">@e.Text</div>
                <div class="col more">Detail</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    public List<QNewsList> News
    {
        set { }
        get
        {
            using (WEKAContext db = new WEKAContext())
            {
                var q = from n in db.Qaktuality select new QNewsList() { Datum = n.Datum.ToString("d.M.YYYY"), Text = new MarkupString(n.Text), Link = n.RssLink };
                return q.ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class QNewsList
    {
        public string Datum;
        public MarkupString Text;
        public string Link;
    }
}
```

Refer to 
https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/167

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12615

Answer (score 21):

It should work when you use this:

```
<div class="col name">@((MarkupString)e.Text)</div>
```